# Airflow: how to run webserver and scheduler together from a docker image?

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm somewhat inexperienced with both Docker and Airflow, so this might be a silly question. I have a Dockerfile that uses the `apache/airflow` image together with some of my own DAGs. I would like to launch the airflow web server together with the scheduler and I'm having trouble with this. I can get it working, but I feel that I'm approaching this incorrectly.

Here is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM apache/airflow
COPY airflow/dags/ /opt/airflow/dags/
RUN airflow initdb
```

Then I run `docker build -t learning/airflow .`. Here is the tough part: I then run `docker run --rm -tp 8080:8080 learning/airflow:latest webserver` and in a separate terminal I run `` docker exec `docker ps -q` airflow scheduler ``. The trouble is, that in practice this generally happens on a VM somewhere, so opening up a second terminal is just not an option and multiple machines will probably not have access to the same docker container. Running `webserver && scheduler` does not seem to work, the server appears to be blocking and I'm still seeing the message "The scheduler does not appear to be running" in Airflow UI.

Any ideas on what the right way to run server and scheduler should be?

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you try to get up both with docker-compose?

Comment: Sure, that or a Kubernetes cluster are valid options, I just thought that there must be a simpler way. Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Compose is far simpler than k8s

Answer (score 3):

First, thanks to @Alex and @abestrad for suggesting docker-compose here -- I think this is the best solution. I finally managed to get it working by referring to [this great post](https://medium.com/@xnuinside/quick-guide-how-to-run-apache-airflow-cluster-in-docker-compose-615eb8abd67a). So here is my solution:

First, my Dockerfile looks like this now:

```
FROM apache/airflow
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --user psycopg2-binary
COPY airflow/airflow.cfg /opt/airflow/
```

Note that I'm no longer copying dags to the VM, this information is going to be passed through volumes. I then build the docker file via `docker build -t learning/airflow .`. My `docker-compose.yaml` looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:

  postgres:
    image: "postgres:9.6"
    container_name: "postgres"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
    - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  initdb:
    image: learning/airflow
    entrypoint: airflow initdb
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  webserver:
    image: learning/airflow
    restart: always
    entrypoint: airflow webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /opt/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
    - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./data/logs:/opt/airflow/logs

  scheduler:
    image: learning/airflow
    restart: always
    entrypoint: airflow scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /opt/airflow/airflow-scheduler.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./airflow/dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./airflow/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
      - ./data/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
```

To use it, first run `docker-compose up postgres`, then `docker-compose up initdb` and then `docker-compose up webserver scheduler`. That's it!

Comment: one suggestion: reduce your image layers by running `RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --user psycopg2-binary `

Comment: @IVR Thanks for sharing. the article you refer to like many others right now is not updated to use the official docker image which you use here. can you share about any pre-processing you did first, such as creating airflow.cfg first, or anything else you didn't mention please?

Comment: @NivCohen, hey, I'd be happy to, but to be honest, I did this quite a while ago now, so I'm afraid I just don't remember anymore. From what I can recall, it wasn't that difficult after I figured out how to run docker compose. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

spinning up two docker containers alone may not achieve your goal, as you would need communications between containers. You can manually set up a [docker network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) between your containers, although I haven't tried this approach personally.

An easier way is to use `docker-compose`, which you can define your resources in a yml file, and let docker-compose create them for you.

```yaml
version: '2.1'
services:
    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.4
        restart: always
        ...
    scheduler:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.4
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - webserver
        ...
```

You can find the complete file [here](https://github.com/tuanchris/cloud-data-lake/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: Well, this would be running two of the same container

Comment: Great, thank you, this is definitely along the lines of what I'm looking for. I'm having 2 problems with this approach: first  if I build the image inside docker-compose file like this `builder: \n build: . \n image: learning/airflow`, running docker-compose up throws an error `airflow subcommand error: 'airflow'`, in other words it doesn't just build the image, it tries to run it. The 2nd problem is that even if I prebuild the image, visiting localhost:8080 shows the airflow UI but there are no DAGs there and it says that the scheduler isn't running even though I can see in logs that it is

Comment: @IVR It will try to run the `ENTRYPOINT` + `CMD` of the container, yes

Answer (score 1):

Note: your question applies to any processes, not only Airflow

It's not recommended, of course, but you can find Docker documentation on `supervisor` which monitors and runs multiple processes under a single `supervisord` daemon

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, but I think the docker-compose solution is a cleaner one here.